# how to get the pushed key using its child in android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to get the pushed key by the help of its child value

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the agency name, then you can create a Firebase Database query to find the matching child nodes with that agency name:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
Query query = ref.orderByChild("agencyname").equalTo("Babaji");
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey()+" "+ dataSnapshot.getChild("agencyname").getValue());
  }
  ...
```

The `onChildAdded` method above will be called for every node with `agencyname` equal to `Babaji`.

I recommend spending some more time in the Firebase documentation, specifically the sections on [dealing with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#read_and_write_lists) and on [querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query =  mDatabase.child("suppliersdata");

 query.orderByChild("agencyname").equalTo("Babaji").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("db", "onDataChange: Key : " + childSnapshot.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
        }
    });
```